# Asp.net core clear cached value when changing value directly in database

Tags: asp.net-core

I changed a value of column for a specific entry directly in my database (postgresql). When looking at the details in my webfrontend of this entry, I see that this value is not updated but is still the old value before changing this in the database (probably because this is cached?). Is their a way to clear this sort of cache?

The only thing I have wrote for caching data is the following in the startup.cs file

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    //Memory cache
    services.AddMemoryCache();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can by `Remove`. When you creating cache you need to set cache key. Use the same key to remove cache. For example:

```
_cache.Remove("CacheKey");
```

Comment: How do you know what key to use? I didn't explicitly added to the cache but cleary the entry I updated in the database is somehow cahced.

Comment: So write how you create your cache

Comment: Well the only thing I added is that what I mentioned in the startup, nothing else.

Comment: Are you using EF Core or other ORM?

Comment: I am using EF Core

Comment: Then use `Reload` on your context. `Reload` is available from EF Core 1.1 (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-entity-framework-core-1-1/)

Comment: Thxs for the help? Is there a way to reload the full database context?

Comment: Unfortunately you need to `Reload` every model in EF Context to get that result

Comment: Thought so :) Thxs for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Problem seemed to be in startup. The database context was set as ServiceLifetime.Singleton, by changing this to ServiceLifetime.Scoped it solved my problem:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    var connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:PostgresConnection"];
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(opts => opts.UseNpgsql(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Default life time for `DbContext` is scoped so u can just remove it

Comment: Ah oke :) Good to know!